# Jdepend package filters

Tags: jdepend

Iam using JDepend to get the dependencies of various packages. There are many packages in my project and i want to filter out some packages with the prefix com.*. In the documentation of JDepend it is given that this can be done by modifing the jdepend.propeties file. I have added the ignore statements in that file but iam unable to filter those out. Can anyone help me?